# Nvidia quantal/main/binary-amd64/Packages 404 Not Found

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix a 404 Error using a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)

I get an 404 error when I try to download Nvidia updates on Ubuntu 12.10 Beta2. The reason why I get this error is simply because there is no distribution folder for quantal

I tried those repos:

http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates/ubuntu/dists/
http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/nvidia/ubuntu/dists/

Any suggestions or explanations? Why is there no quantal folder and how can I install the nvida drivers via ppa (please not manual)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most logical answer: there is no quantal folder because there is no nvidia driver for quantal (yet). Or there is one and the PPA for it does not exist yet.

And yes... in a beta you can expect the answer to be: manual install and since this package is fairly crucial prepare for a re-install when you mess up.

Also: a suggestion: did you check "software settings"/"software sources". I have seen a proposal to add additional driver to that section of Ubuntu. If that made it in you might need to install it from there. This is done by [ubuntu-drivers-common](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/+package/ubuntu-drivers-common).

---

Found it ...

From  my machine:

[image]

Comment: Interesting. Is there a usual date or deadline when they release the Nvidia drivers? Release Candidate or Final Release?

Comment: see my edit @DominicBartl The driver is there but you need to select it from a difference place. Your system is likely to show nvidia here. The bottom one if for the newest version (updates)